# Range v3. Difference between two ranges

Tags: c++, range-v3

I am trying to get the difference between two ranges but have little luck.
Something like

```
vector<int> l{ 1,5,6 };
auto diff = views::ints(1,10) - view::all( l );
==> Range<int> { 2,3,4,7,8,9 }
```

By the way. Are there any good writings on range-v3? Something to make me wiser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `set_difference` algorithm, or its lazy `view` version:

```
#include <range/v3/view/iota.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/set_algorithm.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> l{ 1,5,6 };
    auto diff = ranges::view::set_difference(ranges::view::ints(1,10), l);
    std::cout << diff << '\n'; // [2,3,4,7,8,9]
}
```